# vuejs and openlayers, constructor is not a constructor

Tags: openlayers

```
Uncaught TypeError: Constructor is not a constructor
    at Draw.geometryFunction [as geometryFunction_] (VM2096 app.js:40101)
```

Any idea what causes that? after that, each mouse movement makes an error.

I am trying to draw a polygon
(Laravel, VueJS, OpenLayers)

Comment: welcome to GIS.SE! you have to share some code. it's hard to debug no code... *but*, there is a rather strict definition of what topics fit this board, and pure code reviews most likely get voted as *off-topic*. if there is no direct spatial component, better post/migrate your question on SO or CODEREVIEW.SE even.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I just figured it out... I had 'polygon' and being case sensitive needed to be 'Polygon'

Comment: More code, faster solution :)